# terraform ressource to provision an aws ressource group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

i try to create a terraform resource that provision a terraform ressource group
the point is to create that include the ressources of some cloudformation stack.

i cannot figure out what is the proper way to do this

here is my current testing file :

```
provider "aws" {
}

terraform {
}


resource "aws_resourcegroups_group" "test" {
  name = "test"
  description = "test"
  resource_query {
    query = jsonencode(
      {
        ResourceTypeFilters = [ "AWS::AllSupported",]
        StackIdentifier     = "arn:aws:cloudformation:XXXXXX:XXXXXX:stack/endofarn"
      }
    )
    type = "CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0"
  }
}
```

all i get is :

```
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: expected resource_query.0.type to be one of [TAG_FILTERS_1_0], got CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
│
│   with aws_resourcegroups_group.test,
│   on main.tf line 18, in resource "aws_resourcegroups_group" "test":
│   18:     type = "CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0"
│
╵
```

does anyone know how to write this ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, this might be a bug. GitHub for the terraform AWS provider does not show any issues opened for this, so maybe you can try to submit a bug.

Comment: I am unsure if `CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0` is a type of query. It seems more like a type of resource.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the case as well. Can you take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/APIReference/API_ResourceQuery.html? I can't seem to find why it is not working.

Comment: Are you using latest version of TF and AWS provider? If yes, `CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0` is simply not supported in TF.

Comment: I did open a bug in the aws provider github I will let you know @mark